# Как сделать задержку setTimeout на последнем элементе массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторая функция, которая раз в 1 секунду переключает цвет блоков в массиве добавляя и убирая соответствующий им css класс. Я хотел бы знать, а как сделать так, чтобы таймер остановился, допустим на 5 секунд, когда дойдет до последнего элемента массива, а потом снова продолжил свою работу раз в секунду?

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var mas = document.querySelectorAll("#block");
            var i = mas.length-1;
            var time = 1000;
    (function next() {
         mas[i].classList.add("color");
         i = ++i % mas.length;
         mas[i].classList.remove("color");
         setTimeout(next, time);
     })();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout(next, (i == mas.length - 1)? time * 5 : time);
```